# Проблема с enum в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Имеется следующий код:

```
package oop;

public class LineShape {
    enum ColorRGB{RED,GREEN,BLUE};
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(ColorRGB.RED);
    }
}
```

Который без всяких проблем работает в *Idea* или *Netbeans*, и наотрез отказывается работать в *Eclipse*, выдавая целую кучу ошибок, среди которых странная

> 'enum' should not be used as an identifier, since it is a reserved keyword from source level 1.5 on

Версия java - 8. Так почему простейший код отказывается работать именно в *Eclipse*?

Comment: Ну почему многие на отрез не хотят пользоваться гуглом? Достаточно ввести "eclipse enum" и уже [4 ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811012/can-not-compile-enums-in-eclipse) является ответом на ваш вопрос.

Comment: не воспроизводится. Проверьте настройки проекта: Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В настройках нужно установить compliance level 1.5 или выше

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]